# with clause in union query

Tags: sql

I have with clause in union query like

```
with t1 as(...) ---common for both query
select * from t2
union 
select * from t3
```

how to handle same with cluase in both queries?

Comment: The requirement is not clear, what exactly do you want to do? can you give an example...

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse a Common Table Expression

For example:

```
with cte as 
(
  select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
  from sometable
  where col1 = 42
)
select col1, col2, col3
from cte as t1
union all
select col4, col5, col6
from cte as t2
```

If you need more CTE, then a comma can be used to separate them.

```
with cte1 as 
(
  select col1, col2, col3
  from sometable
  where col1 = 42
  group by col1, col2, col3
)
, cte2 as 
(
   select col4, col5, col6
   from sometable
   where col4 > col5
   group by col4, col5, col6
)
select col1, col2, col3
from cte1 as t1
union all
select col4, col5, col6
from cte2 as t2
```

But in this example it would be more something for aesthetic reasons, by putting the more complicated queries at the top of the SQL.
Because it would be more straightforward to just union the queries from the CTE's together.

```
select col1, col2, col3
from sometable
where col1 = 42
group by col1, col2, col3

union all

select col4, col5, col6
from sometable
where col4 > col5
group by col4, col5, col6
```